# How do I copy the position and rotation of a camera child a-frame entity to use in a scene entity?

Tags: three.js, aframe

I'd like to create a control panel that appears in front of a user when they look down, but then locks itself to the world space.

I'm creating a place holder control panel, and then moving the real control panel to this position and rotation, but the real control panel isn't moving into the place holder spot and stays at position 0 0 0.

However, if I manually execute the process in the console, it works.

This is what I'm trying:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.4.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function createControlPanel() {

      var controlPanelPlaceHolder = document.createElement('a-plane');
      controlPanelPlaceHolder.setAttribute('id', 'control-panel-place-holder');
      document.querySelector('#me').appendChild(controlPanelPlaceHolder);
      document.querySelector('#control-panel-place-holder').setAttribute('width', '0.25');
      document.querySelector('#control-panel-place-holder').setAttribute('height', '0.15');
      document.querySelector('#control-panel-place-holder').setAttribute('position', '0.15 -0.05 -0.3');
      document.querySelector('#control-panel-place-holder').setAttribute('rotation', '-45 0 0');
      document.querySelector('#control-panel-place-holder').setAttribute('color', 'crimson');


      var controlPanel = document.createElement('a-plane');
      controlPanel.setAttribute('id', 'control-panel');
      controlPanel.setAttribute('width', '0.25');
      controlPanel.setAttribute('height', '0.15');
      controlPanel.setAttribute('color', 'teal');
      document.querySelector('a-scene').appendChild(controlPanel);

      document.querySelector('#control-panel-place-holder').object3D.updateMatrixWorld();

      document.querySelector('#control-panel').object3D.position.copy(
        new THREE.Vector3().setFromMatrixPosition(document.querySelector('#control-panel-place-holder').object3D.matrixWorld)
      )

      document.querySelector('#control-panel').object3D.quaternion.copy(
        document.querySelector('#control-panel-place-holder').object3D.getWorldQuaternion()
      )

      document.querySelector('#me').removeChild(document.querySelector('#control-panel-place-holder'));
    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      document.querySelector('a-scene').addEventListener('loaded', createControlPanel);
    });

  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <a-scene debug>
    <a-entity id='me' camera='userHeight: 1.6' position='10 0 10' rotation='0 45 0' look-controls></a-entity>
  </a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm getting the error

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'isPlaying' of null
```

Any thoughts as to why this isn't working?

Thanks.

Comment: You're trying to run JavaScript on DOM elements that haven't yet been initialized. It is recommend to place code within components. https://aframe.io/docs/0.4.0/guides/using-javascript-and-dom-apis.html#where-to-place-javascript-code-for-a-frame

Comment: ok thx kevin. i'll give this a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Using @ngokevin's suggestion, I've moved my code to components and refactored.

The following solution creates a control panel and reticle in front of the user when they look down. The panel stays in position so they can select from it using their reticle. The panel then disappears if they look up.

```js
// helper.js

const q = document.querySelector.bind(document)

function setComponentDefaults(component) {
  for (attr in component.data)
   component.el.setAttribute(attr, component.data[attr])
}
```

```js
// control-panel-skeleton.js

AFRAME.registerComponent('control-panel-skeleton', {

  schema: {
    width:  { default: '0.25' },
    height: { default: '0.15' }
  },

  init: function () {
    setComponentDefaults(this)
  }
})
```

```js
// control-panel-place-holder.js

AFRAME.registerComponent('control-panel-place-holder', {

  schema: {
    id:       { default: 'control-panel-place-holder'},
    position: { default: '0 -0.05 -0.3' },
    rotation: { default: '-45 0 0' },
    visible:  { default: 'false' }
  },

  init: function () {
    setComponentDefaults(this)
  }

})
```

```js
// control-panel.js

AFRAME.registerComponent('control-panel', {

  schema: {
    id:    { default: 'control-panel'},
    color: { default: 'teal'}
  },

  init: function () {

    setComponentDefaults(this)

    this.el.setAttribute('control-panel-skeleton', '')

    const cpHolder = q('#control-panel-place-holder')
    this.el.setAttribute('position', cpHolder.object3D.getWorldPosition())
    this.el.object3D.setRotationFromQuaternion(cpHolder.object3D.getWorldQuaternion())

    q('#reticle').setAttribute('visible', true)
  },

  remove: () => q('#reticle').setAttribute('visible', false)
})
```

```js
// control-panel-trigger.js

AFRAME.registerComponent('control-panel-trigger', {
  init: function () {

    const cp = () => q('#control-panel')

    function createIfLookingDown(detail) {
      if (detail.newData.x < -25 && !cp()) {
        const cp = document.createElement('a-plane')
        cp.setAttribute('control-panel', '')
        q('a-scene').appendChild(cp)
      }
    }

    function removeIfLookingUp(detail) {
      if (detail.newData.x > -20 && cp())
        cp().parentNode.removeChild(cp())
    }

    this.el.addEventListener('componentchanged', (evt) => {
      if (evt.detail.name == 'rotation')
        createIfLookingDown(evt.detail) || removeIfLookingUp(evt.detail)
    })
  }
})
```

```js
  // reticle.js

  AFRAME.registerComponent('reticle', {

    schema: {
      id:             { default: 'reticle' },
      color:          { default: 'brown' },
      cursor:         { default: 'fuse: true' },
      position:       { default: '0 0 -0.1' },
      'radius-inner': { default: '0.003' },
      'radius-outer': { default: '0.0037' },
      raycaster:      { default: 'far: 2' },
      scale:          { default: '1.7 1.7' },
      visible:        { default: 'false' }
    },

    init: function () {
      setComponentDefaults(this)
    }
  })
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src='helper.js'></script>
  <script src='aframe-v0.4.0.js'></script>
  <script src='control-panel.js'></script>
  <script src='control-panel-skeleton.js'></script>
  <script src='control-panel-place-holder.js'></script>
  <script src='control-panel-trigger.js'></script>
  <script src='reticle.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <a-scene debug>
    <a-entity id='me' camera='userHeight: 1.6' position='10 0 10' rotation='0 45 0' look-controls control-panel-trigger>
      <a-ring reticle></a-ring>
      <a-plane control-panel-place-holder control-panel-skeleton></a-plane>
    </a-entity>
    <a-plane color='#888'   rotation='-90 0 0' scale='100 100 0'></a-plane>
    <a-plane color='yellow' rotation='-90 0 0' scale='1 100 0.2'></a-plane>
    <a-plane color='blue'   rotation='-90 0 0' scale='100 1 0.2'></a-plane>
  </a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```